# Show the result in Camunda

Tags: date, validation, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to validate a given date in Camunda and want Camunda to show me the result but I don't know how to receive the result.
please help me.

The Pics:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYjR1.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWeD2.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U1Ui.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw8cM.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The id used when setting the variable is "date".

The id used in the form (process variable name) is "dateResult".

The id in the form need to match the id of the process data you want to show.